# GitHub for Mac - opening already cloned repository

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

The GitHub app for Mac provides options to clone repositories from GitHub or to create new repositories. What if I have already cloned a repository from GitHub using the command line. How can I open it in the GitHub app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try and drag and drop the project folder in the gitHub for Mac application.

See "[Set up your project in GitHub Desktop](https://guides.github.com/introduction/getting-your-project-on-github/index.html#setup)"

[image: https://guides.github.com/introduction/getting-your-project-on-github/mac-dragndrop.jpg]